# AWS Quicksight not able to see athena db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, aws-lake-formation

I'm grasping at straws at this point. I have a Database in LakeFormation and I've given the quicksight service role access to it as well as underlying tables (and their S3 buckets). I've also verified that the quicksight location (us-east-1 N. Virginia) is the same as the s3 bucket locations for the underlying tables. After all of this, when I click on "new dataset" and select Athena, I still can't see my database under the AwsDataCatalog. If I go to athena directly, I can see my DBs + tables there. What else do I need to do?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and it seems QuickSight does not consider the Lake Formation permissions granted to an IAM role or user but rather looks for Lake Formation permissions granted to a specific QuickSight user (or to the QuickSight group to which the QuickSight user belongs).

For QuickSight, Lake Formation permissions thus need to be granted to QuickSight ARNs, e.g. `arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:111122223333:user/default/YourUserName`

[image: Lake Formation screenshot]

Comment: searched this problem for hours, this solution worked perfectly.